# Mean and standard deviation of triplicated vector data

Tags: r, vector, standards, deviation

I have an experiment where I measured a bit less than 200 variables in triplicate.  In other words, I have three vectors of ~ 200 values.

I want a quick way to determine if I should use mean or median for my calculations. I can do the mean easily (`(v1 + v2 + v3) / 3`), but how do I calculate the SD to have it in a vector of ~ 200 SDs? And what about the median? 
After having these values, I need to do growth curves (measurements were taken over certain period of time).

Comment: Do you mean that 3 measurement were taken at time1, time2, time3 and now you want to analyze change in 200 different variables over these 3 time periods? Why then do you want mean or median? Or is it that you took 3 measurements (for accuracy) at each of 200 time periods (time1, time2.... time200)?

Comment: No, the experiment was done in triplicate (600 samples, 3 of each). I need to either average them (if the standard deviation is not huge) or just take the median. This is because, sometimes in biological experiments with living organisms, there is a big variation per se (bugs that tend to clump together, thus not uniformly distributed, border effects in multiwell plates where there is some evaporation, etc.). For one set we had to repeat the whole experiment (we have 4 sets of this assay, meaning we're dealing with 3 (triplicates) x 200 (variables) x 4 species.

Comment: So growth (which you mentioned in your question) is over 200 time periods.

Comment: No, but let me clarify: We have strains of bacteria growing in different media (different sources of carbon and nitrogen) in multiwell plates (96 very small wells). Two different plates per strain, in triplicate (same plate, same strain, 3 plates each). Incubated for 2 weeks, measured every 2-3 days. We need to compare growth among *different strains*, i.e. comparing across same media, ideally same timepoint (this may not be the case, and this is where we need to do some statistical analyses). We need to have one value per strain per timepoint per medium. Mean or average.

Comment: You have got 3 answers how to get mean, sd and median for your triplicate values. But other aspects are also interesting. Maybe you should post separate question for those aspects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a `dplyr` solution:

```
require(dplyr)

d <- data.frame(
  x1 = rnorm(10),
  x2 = rnorm(10),
  x3 = rnorm(10)
  )

d %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(
    mean = mean(c(x1, x2, x3)),
    median = median(c(x1, x2, x3)),
    sd = sd(c(x1, x2, x3))
    )
```

It sounds like you also have a substantive question about longitudinal data. If so, crossvalidated would be a good platform for this question.

Answer (score 0):

`apply` is what you do. Have your vector in a matrix, e.g.

```
mydat <- matrix(rnorm(600), ncol = 3)
means <- apply(mydat, MARGIN = 1, mean) # MARGIN = 1 is rows, MARGIN = 2 would be columns...
sds <- apply(mydat, MARGIN = 1, sd)
medians <- apply(mydat, MARGIN = 1, median)
```

Though I have to say, with 3 values each, using median sounds pretty questionable.

Answer (score 0):

Traditional 'for' loop can also be used, though it is not preferred:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(d)) d[i,4]=mean(unlist(d[i,1:3]))
for(i in 1:nrow(d)) d[i,5]=sd(unlist(d[i,1:3]))
for(i in 1:nrow(d)) d[i,6]=median(unlist(d[i,1:3]))

names(d)[4:6]=c('meanval', 'sdval', 'medianval')

d
           x1         x2         x3     meanval     sdval  medianval
1  -1.3230176  0.6956100 -0.7210798 -0.44949580 1.0363556 -0.7210798
2  -1.8931166  0.9047873 -1.0378874 -0.67540558 1.4337404 -1.0378874
3  -0.2137543  0.1846733  0.6410478  0.20398893 0.4277283  0.1846733
4   0.1371915 -1.0345325 -0.2260038 -0.37444827 0.5998009 -0.2260038
5  -0.8662465 -0.8229465 -0.2230030 -0.63739866 0.3595296 -0.8229465
6  -0.2918697 -1.3543493  1.3025262 -0.11456426 1.3372826 -0.2918697
7  -0.4931936  1.7186173  1.3757156  0.86704643 1.1904138  1.3757156
8   0.3982403 -0.3394208  1.9316059  0.66347514 1.1585131  0.3982403
9  -1.0332427 -0.3045905  1.1513260 -0.06216908 1.1122775 -0.3045905
10 -1.5603811 -0.1709146 -0.5409815 -0.75742575 0.7195765 -0.5409815
```

Using d from @DMC's answer.